# How to install Wine1.9 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, 16.10

I have Ubuntu 16.10 64bit and I need to install wine1.9, but it is a 32 bit program.
I have already tried 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` 
but nothing changed. What should I do?

Comment: What should have changed? What's preventing you from installing Wine? Error messages?

Comment: Oh my mistake, i just find out that the error i encountered was about not finding in the ppa launchpad URL the right wine version for yakkety yak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing WineHQ**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

if it's not working, you can install [wine-staging](http://www.wine-staging.com/)

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
```

Source: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

---

Another approach is to install [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

**Installing PlayOnLinux**

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then go to Tools > Manage wine versions and choose your wine version to install.